# mail output on prompt

Tags: linux, bash, email

I have developed a script in linux bash that is running in background and send emails when something related is found. Here is mail code of that script.

```
mail -s "Backup File place XYZ.... " "$EMAIL"
```

There is no body of that email as everything is covered in subject. but problem is that whenever it sends an email i get ouptput on console saying

```
" Null message body; hope that's ok"....
```

Now I want dont want this text. how can i stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Bash Version 4 onwards

```
mail -s "$text" "$email" &> /dev/null
```

should redirect stdout *and* stderr to /dev/null

Answer (score 1):

You could always just route the output to the bit bucket:

```
 mail -s "Backup File place XYZ.... " "$EMAIL" > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

This, of course, assumes you don't care if you actually see errors there.

Comment: Yes... I'm writing in log file about errors... so i can ignore them here. thanks.